# Jquery Functions submitting at wrong times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My problem current is that I am trying to call a function with jquery at a specific event but it is running at the wrong event. The function I want to call is:

```
function resolvedAjax(tid){
    $.ajax({type: 'post',url: 'resolveTicket.php',data: 'tid=' +tid, success: function(s){
        $('#resolvedTicket').html("Resolved");
        mainTable();
    }});
}
```

I am trying to call it VIA this block of jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewTD', function(){
   var tid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tidTD input').val();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
        url: 'modalInfo.php',
       data: 'tid=' +tid,
       success: function(d){
           $('.modal-body').html(d);
           $('.modal-title').html("Ticket ID: " + tid);
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
           var time = $('#time').val();
           var desc = $('#description').val();
           $("#addComment").click(function(){
           $.ajax({type: 'post', data: { myData: $('#commentAdd').serialize() }, url: "addComment.php", success: function(info){
             $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'modalInfo.php',
                data: 'tid=' +tid,
                success: function(d){
                    $('.modal-body').html(d);
                    $('.modal-title').html("Ticket ID: " + tid);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }});
           }});
           });
       }

   });
   $('#Resolved').click(resolvedAjax(tid));
});
```

The problem is that when I open the modal by clicking the `viewTD` class it runs the function which is not quite what I want. I am trying to get it so that if you click the resolved button inside the modal, which has an ID of `Resolved`, it will run that function. Currently it is running it as soon as it opens and doesn't wait till the resolved button is closed. Is `.click()` not the right trigger? I am trying to optimize this bit of code which is redundant and probably as poorly constructed as can be which is why I am working on function implementations to simplify code and make it more correct but currently this function is having problems and I don't know why.

(Additional information just in case it is needed)
The modal's body is constructed by the first ajax call in the second bit of jquery code. Inside the modal is a table with the ticket information and a form to add comments and the resolve button. I have all this redundant nested code because it was the only way I could get comments to get added and it resolved a few problems (though it has created a few). I think I can get it all working if I can get some of these functions to work but right now I am having the problem of opening the modal and resolving the tickets right away instead of allowing me to view it and add comments correctly.

I know it's probably something simple but I am still trying to learn to use jquery as I have not used it much in the past, sorry if there is any confusion I can try and clarify anything if needed.

Thanks

Edit I have this code now but it is still not working:

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewTD', function(){
       window.tid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tidTD input').val();
       $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
            url: 'modalInfo.php',
           data: 'tid=' +tid,
           success: function(d){
               $('.modal-body').html(d);
               $('.modal-title').html("Ticket ID: " + tid);
               $('#myModal').modal('show');
               var time = $('#time').val();
               var desc = $('#description').val();

           }

       });

    });
    $( document ).on( "click", "#addComment", function() {
        $.ajax({type: 'post', data: { myData: $('#commentAdd').serialize() }, url: "addComment.php", success: function(info){
        }});
    });
    $( document ).on( "click", "#Resolved",  resolvedAjax(window.tid));
```

I can't seem to get tid accessible outside of the scope of that `viewTD` click event. I have tried windows, global variables and objects but can't get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found finally:

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewTD', function(){
       var tid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tidTD input').val();
       modalConent(tid);
       tabID.tableID = tid;
    });
    $( document ).on( "click", "#addComment", function() {
        $.ajax({type: 'post', data: { myData: $('#commentAdd').serialize() }, url: "addComment.php", success: function(info){
            modalConent(tabID.tableID);
        }});
    });
    $( document ).on( "click", "#Resolved", function(){
        resolvedAjax(tabID.tableID);
    });
```

The change I made to fix it was:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#Resolved", function(){
    resolvedAjax(tabID.tableID);
});
```

instead of

```
$( document ).on( "click", '#Resolved', resolvedAjax(tabID.tableID));
```

Not sure why you can't do it the second way but whatever the reason is you have to do it the top way, if someone could comment why I'd sure love that!

@Korgrue's suggestion of getters and setters helped to make the `tid` variable accessible everywhere and helped make this work fully.

Answer (score 1):

Your handler

```
 $("#addComment").click(function()
```

is inside another handler.

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewTD', function(){
```

The second handler does not exist as far as the compiler is concerned because it is in the wrong scope. You need to move that #addComment handler into the root scope. Of course this will require you to rewrite the function - but that is why it is not responding to the clicks.

Also, .click is fine, but a better syntax is using .on because it allows you to scope your handler a little better.

```
  $( document ).on( "click", "#addComment", function() {
      console.log( "foo!");
    });
```

Comment: When I move my addcomment handler into the root scope it doesn't do anything, it doesn't give an error in the inspect element console nor does it call a page in the network pane. I can click the button all I want but nothing happens, this is what was happening earlier which is why I put it in there though I originally did not want to but couldn't figure out how to get it to work outside of that scope. 

I assume by root scope you mean outside of all other scopes.

Comment: I saw your edit after I posted that comment, just to try it I changed to that syntax you posted and that part is working now. I am going to try something similar with the `#Resolved` part and will get back to you! @Korgrue

Comment: I can't get resolved to work outside the scope of that original `viewTD` click event because the `tid` variable is defined only in that scope, can I use a public modifier?

Comment: You can try - but I dont think that the compiler is going to know what to do with that nested handler.

Comment: You're right, I get back unexpected var  if I try to make it public or static or anything. I can't move out the `#Resolved` event because of that `tid` argument but I can't figure out how to get that outside the scope.

Comment: Give TID a getter/setter function in the global scope. You can then reference it from any other scope.

Comment: I added a getter setter object in the global scope and it does save the tid to where I can use it anywhere but I now have a problem that has been causing me trouble for 3 days now, the `#Resolved` click event doesn't trigger outside the scope of the `.viewTD` event. The strange thing is the add comment feature is outside that scope but generated dynamically in the same code the resolve button is generated but it works outside the scope of that function but not the resolved click. @Korgrue